# SQL query for distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have a table as below

```
INTERPRO    GOTERM1  GOTERM2   CONFIDENCE

IPR123      1576     2345       1.000
IPR235      3459     4987       1.000
IPR356      9987     5567       1.000
IPR568      3345     3213       0.88
IPR342      7860     7654       0.88
```

Now I want any of the record with distinct confidence values only like below

```
IPR123   1576    2345   1.000
IPR342   7860    7654    0.88
```

Comment: Well, `IPR123 1576 2345 1.000` and why not `IPR235      3459     4987        1.000`? Define additional criteria to decide which row to select.

Comment: any row with one distinct confidence value is taken .There is no particular criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Using Sql Server 2005+ you can try something like

```
;WITH Vals AS(
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONFIDENCE ORDER BY INTERPRO ) RowID
        FROM    YourTable
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.INTERPRO, t.GOTERM1, t.GOTERM2, t.CONFIDENCE
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  t.INTERPRO = (SELECT MIN(t2.INTERPRO)
                     FROM   tbl t2
                     WHERE  t.CONFIDENCE = t2.CONFIDENCE)
```

**Edit:**

If INTERPRO is non-unique-per-CONFIDENCE:

```
SELECT t2.INTERPRO, t2.GOTERM1, t2.GOTERM2, t1.CONFIDENCE
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT t3.CONFIDENCE FROM tbl t3) t1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 t4.INTERPRO, t4.GOTERM1, t4.GOTERM2
        FROM   tbl t4
        WHERE  t4.CONFIDENCE = t1.CONFIDENCE) t2
```

should work, though I don't have a SQL Server instance handy at the moment to double-check.

Comment: what if there are 2 rows with the same t.INTERPRO?

Comment: I thought of that after I posted and left the computer for the night.  If INTERPRO is not unique per CONFIDENCE, then this wouldn't work, so time for an edit...

Answer (score -1):

if **INTERPRO** is unique

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE INTERPRO in 
(
SELECT MIN(INTERPRO) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CONFIDENCE
)
```

you can replace MIN() with anything you like

Comment: This query will give non-consistent data

Comment: as user489678 said : any row with one distinct confidence value is taken .There is no particular criteria.